# SWF object not playing my XML Playlist

Tags: php, xml, web, flash, swfobject

I've tried to include [youtubetune](http://www.youtubetune.com/) player to social network, but for somereason it wont play the xml files it should play.
I got around issue that the tracks dint even appear by uploading the neccessary swf files and swfobject.js file to my server. Now the tracks appears to the player, but the player wont play them.

You can see my player [here](http://www.munsivu.net/index.php?sivu=profiili&id=1). Scroll down to the player where is one track "Drowning - Rufio" the swf files are in /embed folder and the playlist.xml file is in /Tiedostot/Noctis-/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it.. Seems like i forgot yt.swf file. (I saw that the media player used JW Player)